# Why doesn't this cause a retain cycle in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
class Person {
var hello : (() -> Void)?
var name = "name"

init() {
    print("init \(self)")
}

deinit {
    print("deinit \(self)")
}
}

var person : Person!

person = Person()
person.hello = { () -> Void in
    print("\(person.name)")
}
person = nil
```

And the console output is:

```
init Person
deinit Person
```

In my opinion, because the 'person' is an optional, so Swift keeps a weak reference in the 'hello' closure, is that right?

Comment: Optionals aren't weakly stored. You'd need to declare `person` as `weak` if that's what you want. Weak objects, however, *must* be optionals.

Comment: This was not the original question, please don't transform it until you get all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a retain cycle because the `hello` closure is capturing a variable, and not a constant, and because variables are expected to change in the future, it doesn't retain it, it just holds a reference to it.

Convert it to a constant and you'll obtain the expected retain cycle:

```
func test() {
    let html = Person()
    html.hello = { () -> Void in
        print("\(html.name)")
    }
}
test()
```

This prints only `init Person`, although when the functions ends, `html` goes out of scope and should be deallocated.

The behaviour is equivalent with the `Objective-C` one if you define the variable as `__block`.

Answer (score 1):

Because html is an optional, your closure is actually holding a reference to the enum (Optional) not the object itself so there is only one reference to Person().

If you had created a situation where html actually went out of scope, then there would have been a lingering reference to the Person() object because the capture would be the only remaining reference to the html variable.
But it would still not be the Person() object that has the reference count.

```
 class Person {
 var hello : (() -> Void)?
 var name = "name"

 init() {
     print("init \(self)")
 }

 deinit {
     print("deinit \(self)")
 }
 }

 repeat
 {
    var html : Person

    html = Person()
    // this closure keep a reference to 'html'
    html.hello = { () -> Void in
        print("\(html.name)")
    }

 } while false
```

Comment: Declaring a variable as optional doesn't affect the way it's retained. You're holding a reference to the `Optional` enum, which in turn is holding a reference to the boxed value, so you still get a retain.

Comment: That's not what I was saying.  What I was pointing out is that in the example code, the html variable has a refcount of 2 at some point but Person() never gets a refcount of more than 1.  (same thing in my example BTW).

Comment: Got it, thanks, I misinterpreted the first phrase from your answer.

Comment: When I add html = nil at the end of the while statement above, the person object will be released. And doesn't Swift automatically adds such code at the end of a scope?

Comment: it's not setting it to nil that does the release, it's the html variable going out of scope at the end of the block.  try printing something before and after setting html to nil and you'll see when things actually happen.  (i.e. you're deinit will only be called after the block is completed, so after any print() you do inside of the block.)

Comment: What I mean is that html = nil decrease the refcount of html and thus decrease the person refcount, when going out of scope, they are released. My question is that when you didn't explicitly set html to nil, Swift will not automatically do this.

Comment: They're two different things.  Swift does not set variables to nil automatically.  When a variable goes out of scope, there is no longer a variable to put the nil in.  There is one exception to this which is called a weak reference.    e.g.  weak var html : Person!